# Returning SMS values using PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl

Returning SMS values using PHP Curl.The code below was used to send sms but i need to be able to return values for every action
for instance if sms is ok return value successful, if value is 2904 return SMS sending failed etc.

Any help will be appreciated.
The return values of SMS gateway API are as follows:

```
OK=Successful
2904=SMS Sending Failed
2905=Invalid username/password combination
2906=Credit exhausted




<?php


$data = array(
        'username' => $_GET['username'],
        'password' => $_GET['password'],
        'sender'  => $_GET['sender'],
        // 'sender'  => $_GET['uname'],
        'recipient'  => $_GET['recipient'],
        'message'  => $_GET['message']
);




  // Send the POST request with cURL
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/components/com_spc/smsapi.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$header[ ] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
$header[ ] = "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[ ] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[ ] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[ ] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[ ] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[ ] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[ ] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.



// also tried $header[] = "Accept: text/html";
curl_setopt ($ch,    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
//curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0");


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec($ch); //This is the result from Textlocal
curl_close($ch);



if($result === false) {
//if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {//
echo '<font color=red>Message sending failed</font>';
} else {
echo '<font color=green>SMS  Message also successfully Sent.</font>';

}
print($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

edits: How does it return the values you list? I changed the code below, but it still may not work because I am guessing at the name of the index that it returns the response code:

You are looking for the `curl_getinfo($ch)` command. It returns an array, and you will need to look at that array to find the array key where the return value is stored. I will guess that it is `'http_code'`.

Specifically:

```
if($result === false) {
echo '<font color=red>Message sending failed</font>';
echo '<br>More info:';

$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);

  if ($curl_info['http_code']===2906) {
    echo 'Credit exhausted';
  } elseif ($curl_info['http_code']===2905) {
    echo 'invalid username/password';
  } elseif ($curl_info['http_code']===2904) {
    echo 'SMS failed';
  }

} else {
echo '<font color=green>SMS  Message also successfully Sent.</font>';
}
```

Comment: the code you added throws error below Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\xampp\htdocs\booking_db\smsverify.php