# How to send a SMS through PHP form?

Tags: php, sms-gateway

I have one simple PHP form for sending SMS, I'm trying to send a SMS to one number but it gives me a success message "SMS has sent..." along with the error "Invalid Username/Password".

I manually check the link by putting it in browser it works fine, I have got SMS by this process....

Please help me to solve this!!!

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$number=$_POST['numbertext'].$_POST['number'];
$message=$_POST['message'];


$var="http://sms.************.com/*****.asp?user=username&password=
password&sender=sender&sendercdma=**********&text=".$message."&PhoneNumber=".$number."&track=1";

    echo $var;

    $curl=curl_init('http://sms.************.com/*****.asp');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $var);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result= curl_exec($curl);
    echo $result;
    curl_close($curl);
    die("SMS has sent.....");

    }

?>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post">
Number:<br/>
<input type="text" name="numbertext" />-<input type="text" name="number" />
<br/><br/>

<br/><br/>
Message:<br/>
<textarea name="message"></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which sms api you are using?

Comment: To start, you should `url_encode()` your variables to make sure you have a valid url. And a `var_dump()` of the url will give you more information than an `echo`.

Comment: `user=username&password=password` ? are these the values you are sending?

Comment: no .....they are different!!!

Comment: I expect this should be an SSL connection?

Comment: Have you actually checked the username and password you are sending in the URL are valid and what happens if you copy and paste that url into your browser

Comment: You need to encode url

Comment: what is an output of $var?

Comment: my url works fine by manually.....but through curl it gives error!!!

Comment: Why do you send the url as a post parameter ? Is that what's asked by the API ?

Comment: @RushiKhalkar I am work with msg91 API

Comment: @Anigel It gives "how many message left:25" and message id:"00222".....and i have got sms

Comment: Can you give us a CURL error? You can use curl_error() to get it

Comment: curl_error..."Invalid Username /Password"

Comment: In which case it is a GET not a POST

Comment: @RushiKhalkar You are looking for the curl_getinfo($ch) command. It returns an array, and you will need to look at that array to find the array key where the return value is stored. I will guess that it is 'http_code'. Referance form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002847/returning-sms-values-using-php-curl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sent SMS Through msg91 API,I am still not clear with your API inputs.

```
$YourAuthKey="Your Key";
$mobiles="number";
$message="Transactional Message";
$country=91;
$senderid="XYZMSG";
$url="https://control.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php?authkey=".$YourAuthKey."&mobiles=".$mobiles."&message=".$message."&sender=".$senderid."&route=4&country=91";
echo $url;
header("Location: $url");
```

Answer (score 2):

By checking their api, you should do as follow :

```
$postData = array(
    'authkey' => $authKey,
    'mobiles' => $mobileNumber,
    'message' => $message,
    'sender' => $senderId,
    'route' => $route
);

//API URL
$url="https://control.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php";

// init the resource
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
));
```

And definitely not pass your url as follows :

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $var);
```

Comment: @RushiKhalkar I think so.

Answer (score 0):

```
$YourAuthKey="authkey";
$mobiles="mobile";
$message="demo";
$country=91;
$senderid="625552";// your sender id should be 6 digit
$url="http://********/api/*****.php?authkey=$YourAuthKey&mobiles=$mobiles&message=$message&sender=$senderid&route=4&country=$country";
```

// echo $url;

```
$curl=curl_init('http://*******/api/*****.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $var);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result= curl_exec($curl);
echo $result;
curl_close($curl);
die("SMS has sent.....");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can send SMS using mvayoo api easily 
first create Account on www.mvaayoo.com. Then u will get your username, password detail. Fill this detail in following code and send SMS easily

```
<?php$ch = curl_init();
 $user="enter your account email id here:enter your password here";
 $receipientno="enter recivermobile number here";
 $senderID="TEST SMS";
 $msgtxt="this is test message, test";
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"user=$user&senderID=$senderID&receipientno=$receipientno&msgtxt=$msgtxt");
 $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
 if(empty ($buffer)){
   echo " buffer is empty ";
 }else{
   echo $buffer;
 }
 curl_close($ch);
>
```

www.gajabwap.blogspot.in